# upload file restritions in php

Tags: php

I have written a code for uploading any file and have also applyied certain restrictions. But now when i try to upload any viedo it is not showing any error it is just showing a blank screen.
I have written it for images.I am confused about what to write for others.
my code is as follows

```
 <?php
session_start();
define ("MAX_SIZE","4000"); 
define ("WIDTH","750"); 
define ("HEIGHT","563");

   function getExtension($str) 
{
    $i = strrpos($str,".");
    if (!$i) 
    {
         return "";
     }
    $l = strlen($str) - $i;
    $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
    return $ext;
}

$errors=0;



        if(isset($_POST['Upload']))
        {

    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];


    if ($image) 
    {
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
            $size=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $sizekb=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

            if ($sizekb > MAX_SIZE*1024)
            {
                echo '<h1>You have exceeded the size limit!</h1>';
                $errors=1;
            }

            $image_n=time();
            $image_name=$image_n.'.'.$extension;
            //$image_name1="vimal".$extension;
            echo "<br> Image  Name " . $image_name;
            echo "<br> " . $_SESSION['Id'];
            $newname=$_SESSION['Id'] ."/upload/".$image_name;
            $copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
            //$copied1 = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $image_name1);


        if (!$copied) 
        {
            echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessfull!</h1>';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {
                echo "Your databaase Insert Code Here";
            include ("config.php");

            $st = "insert into file_master values('".$_SESSION['Id'].$image_n ."','" . $extension . "','".$image_name."','".$_SESSION['Id'] ."/upload/".$image_name. "','".$_SESSION['Id']."','N')" ;
            echo "<br>". $st;
            try
            {
                mysql_query($st);
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
            }
}
    }   
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: If you have a blank screen but don't expect one, you need to turn on error reporting because you have a fatal syntax error.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  Always develop with this turned on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: It is still showing me the blank screen. I think there is a problem in coding , I have not written any conditions for files with more size.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not an answer, i wish to share with you many useful techniques relative to your code and the way you coded it.

**Getting a file's extension**

```
$extension = end(explode('.', basename($completepath)));
```

Instead of checking using complex instructions, just take the file's name (basename) and then explode on the period and take the last item of the generated array...

**Checking if a file was correctly uploaded**

```
if(is_file_uploaded($_FILES['nameofinput']['tmp_name'])){
```

This will use the standard secure methods for checking if a file actually exists for real. The other function you should use is

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['nameofinput']['tmp_name'], $targetfilename);
```

This will ensure that you only try to move a file you should have access to normaly and will prove to be effective against hackers trying to abuse from your system by tweaking the input data.